# Tikz animations library: begin on =key

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, svg

The Pgf manual states that you can start an animation (as in tikz library animations) when pushing a keyboard key. There is no example though, so the syntax is unclear.
I took an example from [the pgf manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-animations) and I tried to modify it so it starts when the spacebar is pushed:

```
\tikz \node :rotate = { 0s="0", 2s="90", begin on = {key=Space} }
  [fill = blue!20, draw = blue, circle, ultra thick] {Here!};
```

... but nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does any letter work?  Both tikz.dev as well as the official PDF manual state: “For security reasons, a viewer may suppress this.” I couldn't get any of the keys in this [SVG file on Wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikibooks/de/b/b6/SVGbegin_accessKey01.svg) working in my Firefox instance. That said, that file uses `U+0020` (32 in decimal) for space.

Comment: Firefox' devtools tell me about an unexpected value with all of them (ours and the one of Wikimedia). Make sure that ordinary letters/keys work and it's not a viewer problem and then tackle the space key (which is despite its size somewhat special).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel
I could'nt get it to work . I asked a similar question on the pgf-tikz forum but no one has answered yet.